# jQuery Twitter feed not working with specific account

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm using this twitter feed: http://coda.co.za/content/projects/jquery.twitter

For our organization's account, it won't list recent tweets. However, I can input my personal account (or McDonald's for that matter...) and it will list recent tweets. Any idea what could be causing this? Some setting?

Here's the example:
http://oursaviorschurch.com/twittertest.html
http://oursaviorschurch.com/personaltwittertest.html

Comment: Do you have some oauth account setup? Something for API 1.1?

Comment: Dude I'm going to be honest, I have no idea what that means.

Comment: He means to ask if you have set up the necessary Twitter accounts to get your security access tokens. Take a look at the SETUP_INSTRUCTIONS document on the plugin page that I linked to and it will guide you through this.

Comment: Check the plugin page (http://zkniebel.github.com/jquery-twitter-feed/) - I updated the PHP example and added a new PHP file, in the "Plug and Play" directory. All you have to do is fill in your tokens/keys and the Twitter handle that you want to use and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and I hope this helps lots of other people!

Comment: Please upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped you - that way other people know that it is good and helpful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually posted this as an answer to a couple other questions. Sorry about the repetition, but I think this will save you a lot of time:

I just updated a [plugin](http://zkniebel.github.com/jquery-twitter-feed/) to work with the Twitter 1.1 API. The likely cause of this issue is that Twitter may have already shut down that part of the API 1.0. You will have to upgrade to the new one, and the plugin should help.

Unfortunately, per Twitter's urging, you will have to perform the actual request from server-side code. However, you can pass the response to the plugin and it will take care of the rest. I don't know what framework you are running, but I have already added sample code for making the request in C# or PHP. Even if you do not wish to use the rest of the plugin, the instruction document should help you set up the necessary accounts on Twitter to get started.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you @zachary-kniebel - any idea though why it is working with certain accounts and not with others?

Comment: It could be that certain accounts have different permissions, or it could be something else related to their API. I haven't examined the code in the plugin that you used well enough to know its intricacies, but I would imagine that it has something to do with some filtering parameter passed in the query string that is immaterial on some queries. The truth is, it wouldn't matter if I knew the code in and out, as it is making a call to a deprecated, unstable and partially shut-down API :( In the next 10 days it likely would have stopped working anyway.

Comment: Oh gotcha - thank you so much man. Do you have any demos of your plugin in action? I didn't see any on your site

Comment: There is one that will be launching pretty soon. If you need to get it working sooner, I can help you implement it. Take a look at the SETUP_INSTRUCTIONS document, and you will see what is needed to make it work. What is your server-side code base?

Comment: I'm working in PHP, it's actually a WP site but I'm just putting it in on the home page manually.

Comment: Ok, if I have time, I will post a demo tonight. I will leave a comment if I do. In the meantime, I would still read through the literature and setup the necessary accounts on Twitter. You will have to do this regardless of what tool you use, if you decide that you still want to have Twitter on your site. Note that the jQuery side of my plugin is just meant to simplify the rendering of a Twitter timeline.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26576/discussion-between-tstrebeck-and-zachary-kniebel)

Comment: If this answer helped you and/or solved your problem, please upvote and/or accept it